# How to get the HTTP status code from within the $.get ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to get the error status code if the ajax $.get fail.

```
$.get("url", getParamsForAddress(), function (result) {
               //something                
        }).error(function () {
            var statusCode = //get status code
        });
```

Comment: It's in the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using like

```
.error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   var statusCode = xhr.status;
 });
```

You can get the status codes (200, 400, 500 etc) via the status property of the xhr object.